# Make linked directories

Tags: java, mysql

I have a class that pulls in an id, name and (if needed) parent-id, it converts these into objects and then links them.

If you look right at the end you will see what Im trying to fix at the moment, The folder objects know if they have a child and/or parent but if I were to run mkDirs() here it would only work for two levels (root, child-folder) but if there were multipul levels (root/folder1/folder1) it would not work.

Any Idea how I can solve this?

```
package stable;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
public class Loop {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int PID = 0;

    int RepoID = 1;
    Connection con = null;
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/document_manager";
    String user = "root";
    String password = "Pa55w0rd";
    try {
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Map<Integer,Folder> data = new HashMap<Integer,Folder>(); 
    while( PID < 50 )
    {
    try {            
        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet result = st.executeQuery("SELECT name, category_id, parent_id FROM categories WHERE parent_id = '"+PID+"' AND repository_id = '"+RepoID+"'");
        while (result.next ())
        {
            String FolderName = result.getString ("name");
            String FolderId = result.getString ("category_id");
            String ParentId = result.getString ("parent_id");
            int intFolderId = Integer.parseInt(FolderId);
            int intParentId = Integer.parseInt(ParentId);
            System.out.println( FolderId+" "+FolderName+" "+ParentId );
            Folder newFolder = new Folder(FolderName, intFolderId, intParentId);
            data.put(newFolder.getId(), newFolder);
            }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
  PID++;
    }
    for(Folder folder : data.values()) {    
        int parentId = folder.getParentFolderId();
        Folder parentFolder = data.get(parentId);
        if(parentFolder != null)
            parentFolder.addChildFolder(folder);
        //Added
        System.out.print("\n"+folder.getName());
        if(parentFolder != null)
            System.out.print("  IS INSIDE "+parentFolder.getName());
        else
            System.out.print("  HAS NO PARENT!");

    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you could/should break out the directory creation logic into its own function and then make it recursive.  That should get you the ability to make 'infinite' depth directory hierarchies.

Side note:  Its horribly inefficient to make repeated DB calls in a loop.  Try a single Select and then loop thru results.  If needbe, you can use SQL's 'IN' operator to filter results:
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp